Unable to create categories and tags for posts in wordpress multisite
Good morning everyone,
I inherited a wordpress multisite. Now I need to create a blog as a sub-folder site but it is impossible for me to generate new categories, or rather the number of categories present appears but they are not displayed and it is not possible to link them from the articles.
Also the select menu of the post default category in the settings section is empty.
In the main site, however, the categories are created without problems.
What could be the problem?
Thank you very much



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
